# Variable does not exist, when trying to assign values to wrapper properties

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, developer

I am trying to create a custom controller and populate a wrapper class that will be used on a Visualforce page. Two unique values and multiple lists of the holdings. I am getting errors that say "Variable does not exist" for the wrapper properties in the get method. I have tried putting the object being passed inside and outside of the for loop be can still not seem to figure out why.

```
    public class DataWrapper {
        public String Custodian { get; set; }
        public String AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public List<FinServ__FinancialHolding__c> RowData { get; set; }
 
        public DataWrapper(Account acct, String Custodian, String AccountNumber, List<FinServ__FinancialHolding__c> RowData, Decimal TotalValue) {
            this.Custodian = Custodian;
            this.AccountNumber = AccountNumber;
            this.RowData = new  List<FinServ__FinancialHolding__c>();
        }
    } 

  //Data query
        List<FinServ__FinancialHolding__c> rowData = [SELECT FinServ__FinancialAccount__r.Name, FinServ__FinancialAccount__r.Custodian__c,
                                                        FinServ__FinancialAccount__r.Date_Validated__c, FinServ__FinancialAccount__r.FinServ__FinancialAccountNumber__c, 
                                                        FinServ__Symbol__c, FinServ__Shares__c, FinServ__Price__c, FinServ__MarketValue__c
                                                      FROM FinServ__FinancialHolding__c
                                                      WHERE FinServ__FinancialAccount__r.FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
                                                        AND FinServ__FinancialAccount__r.FinServ__FinancialAccountNumber__c IN :strAcctIds];
       
        //Assigning values to properties
       List<DataWrapper> TableData = new List<DataWrapper>();  //outside loop
       
       for(FinServ__FinancialHolding__c id: rowData)
       {     
           //List<DataWrapper> TableData = new List<DataWrapper>();  //inside loop
           
           TableData.AccountNumber.add(id.AccountNumber__c);
           TableData.Custodian.add(id.Custodian__c);
           TableData.RowData.add(id);        
       }
  
 return TableData;
```

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is the issue or not, but you don't get the implicit no-arg constructor if you provide _any_ constructor. So `new List<DataWrapper>();` is likely the (or an) issue. If that's the case, then the issue should disappear if you define your own no-arg constructor (in addition to keeping the one you have that takes 5 arguments).

Comment: @Derek F, Create something similar? i.e.    public class DataWrapper {
        public String Custodian { get; set; }
        public String AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public List<FinServ__FinancialHolding__c> RowData { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add individual objects to a list, rather than trying to add objects to the elements in the object. For your code to work, you'd have to have a DTO that looks like:

```
class DataDto {
  List<String> accountNumber = new List<String>();
  List<Id> custodian = new List<Id>();
  // ... etc
}
```

Which you'd initialize in your main code as:

```
DataDto TableData = new DataDto();
```

That's not what you meant to do, presumably.

Instead, you need to create a new individual DTO object inside the loop:

```
   for(FinServ__FinancialHolding__c id: rowData)
   {     
       DataDto dto = new DataDto();       
       dto.AccountNumber = id.AccountNumber__c;
       // ... etc
       TableData.add(dto);        
   }
```

Again, I'd recommend that you remove the constructor you've written so you can use the default constructor.